# How do I make a graph fill a specific range? Also, how do I use VBA to change the size of the markers in a graph?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

How do I make a graph fill a specific range? I found out how to do it using VBA a while ago, but I can't for the life of me find out how to do it again. I'd like a graph to fill a specific range, like F1 to K8. That way if the other columns to the left change due to user input, the graph while still stay in that range, making everything look nice.

My second questions is, how do I change the size of the markers on an excel graph using VBA? I'm plotting thousands of data points, and the default markers are huge diamonds, so the graph looks ridiculous with thousands of these. The line is just this incredibly thick thing.

And one extra bonus question! I'm making the entire graph using VBA. There are two series I'm making. However, when inserting the two series, it adds a third series with no data points in it. It wouldn't be annoying if it didn't show up in the legend. How do I delete a series?

Thank you! Here is the relevant code. Counter and NewTracker are variables that are based on user input. I believe Counter = 13 and NewTracker = 1202 for the data I'm using, but I don't think it matters based on my questions here! Just replace the ranges with something nicer if you feel like using an example. :)

```
Sub Makingthechart()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet1!$B$1"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$" & Counter + 1
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$" & Counter + 1
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "CFL Calculated"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = "=Sheet1!$XFB$1:$XFB$" & NewTracker
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=Sheet1!$XFC$1:$XFC$" & NewTracker
    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveChart
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "CFL Over Time"
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Time (Days)"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "CFL"
        .Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
        .Axes(xlCategory).HasMinorGridlines = True
    End With
End Sub
```

I seriously appreciate all of your help! You guys are the reason I've been pretty successful in my internship so far! I can't believe you guys know all these tiny things about VBA that I can't even find via Google.

Comment: A `ChartObject` has `Top` and `Left` properties, which you can set to the Top and Left of cell F1. Then set the `Width` and `Height` to the Width and Height of the range you want to plot to cover.

Comment: I want to believe, but I can't find evidence of that. I feel like I should be able to do something like **With ActiveChart, .Left = Cells(something)** but I can't find anything like that.

Comment: On a worksheet, charts are hosted in a `ChartObject`, so it's this object whose Top and Left you need to set.  You can't set the position of the Chart itself, only it's container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub Makingthechart()
    Dim co As Shape, cht As Chart
    Dim rngChart As Range, sc As SeriesCollection

    Set rngChart = ActiveSheet.Range("F2:J15")


    Set co = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlXYScatter, rngChart.Cells(1).Left, _
                                          rngChart.Cells(1).Top, _
                                          rngChart.Width, rngChart.Height)

    Set cht = co.Chart
    Set sc = cht.SeriesCollection

    'remove any default series
    Do While sc.Count > 0
        sc(1).Delete
    Loop

    With sc.NewSeries
        .Name = "=Sheet1!$B$1"
        .XValues = "=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$" & counter + 1
        .Values = "=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$" & counter + 1
        .MarkerSize = 3
    End With

    With sc.NewSeries
        .Name = "CFL Calculated"
        .XValues = "=Sheet1!$XFB$1:$XFB$" & newtracker
        .Values = "=Sheet1!$XFC$1:$XFC$" & newtracker
        .MarkerSize = 3
    End With

    With cht
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "CFL Over Time"
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Time (Days)"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "CFL"
        .Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
        .Axes(xlCategory).HasMinorGridlines = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This works! THANK YOU! So is sc.Count the amount of series on the chart? So that Do While loop is deleting the series until there are zero?